# Как настроить репликацию в MS SQL server не всей таблицы полностью, а конкретных столбцов?

Tags: sql-server, репликация

Дорогие коллеги, помогите пожалуйста решить дилемму.

Архитектура БД (таблицы и поля) во всех БД идентичны.

Нужно настроить однонаправленную репликацию между БД1 и каждой из локальных БД (БД2, БД3, БД4, БД5).

Репликация неполная(выборочная), определенный набор таблиц с определенным набором столбцов.

Пример: при изменении данных в БД1, во всех локальных БД (БД2, БД3, БД4, БД5), также должны произойти изменения, но только для тех таблиц и полей, которые были указаны в публикации.

Для этих целей была выбрана репликация транзакций (т.к. необходима и оперативность репликации). Но каким бы образом я не пытался ее настроить, желаемого результата не получил.

В зависимости от выставленного параметра "Действие, если имя уже используется" (в свойствах статьи), репликация либо удаляет на подписчике не отмеченный в публикации столбец(путем пересоздания таблицы). Либо не реплицирует данные вовсе. Исправно реплицируются данные только в случае выбора всех столбцов таблицы.

Помогите пожалуйста, как все таки правильно настроить, что бы реплицировались изменения только в отдельных столбцах? И возможно ли это в MS SQL server?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Используй схему IF Not Insert then Modify...
Если с ERP завязки то все просто проводи с параметром FALSE...

Чтобы и в ERP не отработали триггеры и на стороне SQL сервер просто были внесены "незаметные преобразования" ....

Да, может нарушить целостность данных, но коль уж так необходимо...

С Уважением,
Сергей

Comment: а это точно ответ на вопрос про настройку репликации?